# Amenability of groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, amenability

Let $G$ be non-amenable finitely generated group.

1) Is it true that there exists a sequence $S(n)$ of sets which generate $G$ and such that

$\frac{1}{|S(n)|}||\sum_{g\in S(n)} \lambda(g)||\rightarrow 0$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$.

2) The same as (1), but $S(n)$ is finite subset of $G$.

Here $\lambda:G\rightarrow B(l^2(G))$ is left regular representation of $G$.

Also 1) is reformulation of 2).

**Edit:** [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55075/amenability-of-groups-iii) are some discussions on the question.

Comment: What's $\lambda$?

Comment: It must be the left regular representation, and the norm must be the operator norm in $l^{2}(G)$, right?


Comment: The questions, assuming Jon is right as to the notation, are equivalent: 1) obviously implies 2), and if you have a sequence $S(n)$ satisfying 2), then fix a finite generating set $T$ and consider the family $S'(n):=S(n)\cup T$. Simple argument using triangle inequality shows that $S'(n)$ give you the answer to the first question. I find the question interesting but I won't upvote unless you explain your notation explicitly. 

Comment: @Lukasz: How do we know that $S(n)\cup T$ doesn't very quickly become empty? There doesn't seem to be any stipulation that S(n) eventually exhausts G. Ditto on the need for clarification.

Comment: @Jon: It's enough to show that if S(n) fulfills 2) then |S(n)| is unbounded. This is clear since $(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda(g_i))(e) = \sum_{i=1}^n g_i$, and this last vector has $l^2$-norm $n^{\frac{1}{2}}$, which gives a lower bound on the norm of the operator $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda(g_i)$.

Comment: Echoing Jon's comment: could you please specify what norm you are taking? Also, when you say this sequence "generates" $G$, is this the same as saying that it exhausts $G$?

Comment: In both 1 and 2, S(n) is finite set

Of course 1 and 2 are equivalent, I wanted to specify how 2 is related to generators of G in general.

The given norm is the norm of the left regular representation, computed on $l^2(G)$.

Of course if one assumes that $S(n)$ is given with "multiplicities", then the answer for the question is positive. 



Comment: Oops. I did mean to say the operator norm, as in the norm on $B(l^{2}(G))$. That is what you mean, right?

Comment: @ Jon Bannon: $||\lambda(g)||:=||\lambda(g)||_{B(l^2(G))}$

Comment: @Jon: thanks for asking. I've corrected the question, now I hope it is readable.

Comment: @Yemon Choi: in 1, for each n, S(n) generates G as group.

Comment: @Kate: It's readable, and I think a really nice question!

Comment: one more remark: The statement is true for free groups and thus for groups that contain free groups.

Comment: @Kate: Is it related to unitarizability and Dixmier? 

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of this old result of H. Kesten: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=112053 (at least in the case where we assume each S(n) to be symmetric)

Comment: @ Mark: it is not related to Dixmier problem, at least from what I know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was proved by Nagnibeda-Smirnova and myself (http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.2183) that if a group $\Gamma$ contains an infinite  normal subgroup $N$ such that $\Gamma/N$ is not amenable then the question above for $\Gamma$ is true. This gave many examples of groups which are non-amenable and does not contain $\mathbb{F}_2$ as a subgroup, such as Burnside and Golod-Shafarevych groups. As an easy consequence: if $\Gamma$ is not amenable then for $\Gamma\times \mathbb{Z}$ the question is true.

The question in the complete generality was finally solved by Andreas Thom (http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.1767)

There are applications to percolation theory (due to Nagnibeda-Pak) and to operator space analog of von Neumann's conjecture (due to Pisier) listed in the citations above.

To my current knowledge (please correct me here), the question itself should be contributed either to Gilles Pisier or to Nagnibeda-Pak.